# Pandas categorical not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to learn how ordinal scale (categorical) works in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

student = ["alex","bob","cynthia","daniel","evans"]
tshirt = ["L","XL","S","M","L"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = tshirt, index=student)
df = df.rename(columns={0:"tshirt"})




       tshirt
  alex    L
  bob     XL
  cynthia S
  daniel  M
  evans   L

df = df["tshirt"].astype("category", categories = ["S","M","L","XL"],ordered = True)
```

When I tried the following code, it shows as True.

```
df.loc["alex"] < df.loc["daniel"]
```

It should be False (because L > M)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are comparing the strings.

Comment: What's the right way to compare the values? I wanna check whether Alex's tshirt size is shorter than Daniel's tshirt or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `df` is actually a `Series`... but in any event, the problem is you are comparing the *values*, which are strings, which have an inherent ordering (lexicographic), and that is what Python is doing. You need to select your data in a way that returns `pandas` data structures:

```
In [2]: df[['alex']] < df[['daniel']]
Out[2]:
alex    False
Name: tshirt, dtype: bool
```

Or

```
In [3]: df.loc[['alex']] < df.loc[['daniel']]
Out[3]:
alex    False
Name: tshirt, dtype: bool
```